# Applying for b2 visa for my kids, we have non immigrant visa

Tags: visas, b1-b2-visas, children

My husband and I have b2 visas already.  We want to apply for B2 visas for our 3 kids too, what is the process for this?

Can I use my existing username in the US consular website and just delete my information and put my kids info or should I retain the info of my and my husband and just add them?

Comment: @Phoog Fair point, I’ll delete

Comment: @Traveller it wasn't necessarily a rhetorical question.

Comment: @Phoog :-) I just wondered, if the parents’ visa is recent, whether not intending to travel without their children was part of the basis of their application, and if so, how US immigration authorities might view a subsequent application for the children.

Comment: @Traveller I suppose that's a concern.  It seems to me that UK authorities are more likely to take exception to that sort of thing than US authorities, but I could certainly imagine that US authorities might also in some circumstances.